# Using Short Urls When Posting Tweets With CodeBird (PHP)

Tags: php, twitter, short-url, codebird

I'm currently using [CodeBird](https://github.com/jublo/codebird-php) to post tweets via PHP on my website. I've been using Bit.ly to post short URLS within those tweets. I would prefer to use the t.co short links that twitter creates but I am unsure how to do this.

```
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("???", "???");
$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken("???", "???");

$params = array('status' => $VideoTitle.' | Visit -> '.$VideoShortUrl, 'media[]' => 'hdefault.jpg');

$reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($reply), True);
```

Above is the code I use alongside the codebird.php file. Every tweet includes a title, url, and image. I'm looking to have the link I post (which is always 28+ characters) replaced with the twitter t.co short link.

I've read the twitter API documentation and other related questions on SOF but still have come up empty handed. I know twitter creates the link as soon as I post a tweet cause the array returns the short URL with all the other tweet details instantly.

The Twitter API says:

> Links will be wrapped when Twitter receives a Tweet using POST statuses/update or a direct message using POST direct_messages/new.

I was thinking maybe codebird's wrapper wasn't unwrapping the links when it was returning the data, but I couldn't find anything there either. Does anyone know how I would go about replacing my URL with the t.co URL in the process of posting a tweet?

p.s

I've read that sometimes the short url creation 'could' be delayed, but none of my links are being changed. Also on a side note almost all the tweets are under 140 characters even with the long URL.

Answer (score 1):

Every link posted to Twitter gets wrapped in the API.  You don't need to do anything specific - just include a URl in your status.

When Twitter displays the tweets on its website, it will often show the original URL, but when you click on it, it goes via t.co

Can you show us an example of one of your Tweets which doesn't have a t.co link?